# give the definition of $g(x) = o(x^3)$

Tags: limits, definition, infinitesimals

The exercise says to give the definition of $g(x) = o(x^3)$  for $x\to 0$ :

what I know is that "$o$" means :

$$\lim_{x\to u} {f(x)\over g(x)} = 0$$

and that :

$$f = o(g)$$

does that mean that :

$$\lim_{x\to 0} {g(x)\over x^3} = 0?$$

Comment: Yes, $g(x)=o(x^n)$ iff $\lim_{x\to 0} g(x)/x^n=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. By definition, as $x \to 0$, one has
$$
g(x)=o(x^3)
$$ *if and only if*
$$
\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{g(x)}{x^3}=0.
$$

Comment: how can I format math formulas like you , is there a website where I can learn ?

Comment: @NPLS Please have a look here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference